# Finding the index of a specific type of element relative to the entire page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several images sorted like this:

```
<div>
    <img src="img.png"><img src="img.png"><img src="img.png">
</div>
<div>
    <img src="img.png"><img src="img.png"><img src="img.png">
</div>
<div>
    <img src="img.png"><img src="img.png"><img src="img.png">
</div>
```

When using `.index()`, it returns the index relative to the parent. So if I used it on the second element of the third row, it would return 1 when I would want it to return 7. Is there a way to get the index relative to the entire page, as well as only counting `img` tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you're using jQuery, it should be relatively easy.

```
jQuery('img').index(jQuery(this));
```

This will show the current image's index comparative to all other images on the site. Example usage:

```
jQuery('img').on('click',function(){ 
    console.log(jQuery('img').index(jQuery(this)); //will return index based on all images
});
```

The click function should demonstrate that the index is based on all images, not just images with the same parent.